# Js не проигрывать анимацию на скрытой вкладке

Tags: javascript

Есть страница, в которой проигрывается анимация каждые 5 сек, примерно так:

```
setInterval(function() {
    randomChange(lastindex);
}, 5000);
```

Так вот если перейти на другую вкладку браузера и вернуться на страницу через некоторое время, то проигрываются все анимации разом, которые вызвались за каждые 5 сек, как это можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [AnimationFrame](http://html5.by/blog/what-is-requestanimationframe/)

Анимация не будет проигрываться, если вкладка не активна. Совсем, что решает проблему с накоплением вызовов, при использовании `setInterval`

По ссылке можете прочитать, что это такое, а ниже пример ( из ссылки )

```
var time;
function step() {
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
        dt = now - (time || now);

    time = now;

    // для примера сдвиг по оси х
    this.x += 10 * dt; // Увеличивать х на десять единиц в секунду
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил просто) Отследив активность вкладки

```
var intq = setInterval(function () {
    randomChange(lastindex);
}, 5000);

window.onblur = function () {
    clearInterval(intq);
}
window.onfocus = function () {
    var intq = setInterval(function () {
        randomChange(lastindex);
    }, 5000);
}
```